# Why do car batteries cost less than UPS batteries?

Tags: batteries

I want to have a UPS that consists of a 12V battery and an inverter to 220V AC output. I want it to work with up to 100W supply for 2-4 hours offline.

Searching the web shops I see that 12V batteries for cars with about 60Ah cost less than "regular" or "for uninterruptible power supply" 12V battery with 30Ah.

Is it local specification in my country, or there is a trick in batteries for cars?

[image]

Comment: When you say "accumulator" do you mean battery? And are you comparing a 12V battery to a UPS? A UPS contatins a lot more than just a battery. It has a charger, inverter and other bit so equipment to monitor the supply so that it is not interrupted.

Comment: @Puffafish, probably battery, a thing that accumulates electrical energy. I do not compare a battery and an UPS, I compared an item in the shop that marked as "battery for car" and another item, that marked as "just a battery" or "just a battery (for UPS)"

Comment: An "accumulator" is an old fashion term for capacitor, not a battery.

Comment: @DKNguyen As I understand it, it's also a (perhaps also old-fashioned) word for a rechargeable battery in some languages.

Comment: @Hearth, in Russian or Ukrainian word "battery" is rather used for small cylindrical batteries like in TV remotes (A, AA, AAA, etc.) and less frequently may be used for phone batteries. "Accumulator" is used for something more "heavy"

Comment: Funny, because _technically_ speaking, the cylindrical objects labelled, "AA," and "AAA," and "C," and "D" are individual _cells,_ not batteries of cells.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, also, although big battery can be a bit weirdly called as battery, cells are never called as accumulators, it would be very weird. By the way, a radiator (heating) is called battery (not accumulator), never called as radiator.

Comment: @DKNguyen - in English speaking countries, 'accumulator' usually means 'rechargeable battery', and is a bit old fashioned, but not totally obsolete.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey So it sounds like at some point accumulator meant rechargeable battery *and* capacitor at some point. How confusing. Though there was also "condenser".

Comment: @DKNguyen - I have been reading about electrical and electronic topics in English for over 60 years (my father was an electrical engineer), including material from before 1900, and I have _never_ seen 'accumulator' used to mean anything other than what Cambridge Dictionary defines as 'a battery that collects and stores electricity'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey What can I say? I've run into a few times which is the only reason I know the term at all and I've never been out of North America. This is the first time I've seen it refer to a battery.

Comment: @DKNguyen - OK - Wikipedia says _Capacitor, in electrical engineering, also known by the **obsolete** term accumulator_ - I'd never heard of it before.

Comment: In some German-derived languages, akumulator is old-fart speak for battery.

Comment: @DKNguyen, "condensator" (конденсатор) is a capacitor in Slavic languages. Congrats, now You are completely confused

Comment: @Ngdgvcb That matches condenser which is another old fashion term for capacitor.

Answer (score 6):

"batteries" come in several 'flavours".

Car batteries are designed to delivery a very high current (500A or more - for trucks 1000A) over a short period of time and then get recharged relatively quickly. Also they are not designed to do many full discharge / recharge cycles.

Then there are the "deep cycle" batteries designed for leisure use which support a deeper discharge compared to car batteries and can sustain high currents (but not as high as car batteries).

The "deep cycle" batteries designed for use with ups etc are designed to discharge 80% or so of their capacity and do this for repeated cycles.

The cycling is what will kill a car battery in very short order. My son used two car batteries (100AH) to provisionally test his solar pv off-grid system. After 5 months the batteries were dead.

Now he has two deep cycle gel batteries working in the same conditions and they are still working after two years. Of course the cost is different :)

Comment: Well, I need battery only because there is a war, and we have electricity for 4 hours per day, so I need it only for half year I think. I need it just for 30W monitor, some basic 24W charger, maybe 10W light bulb, of course it all with 12V-220V UPS.

Comment: As I understand, car battery should not be discharged less than 50%, so 60W/12V = 5Ah, + 20% energy loss on UPS transformer, probably should be about 8Ah. So, using the setup for 4 hours, it should cost about 32 Ah per day, so I need approximately 70 Ah battery, and recharge it every day.

Comment: What do You mean by *many* recharge cycles? How many exactly?

Comment: @Ngdgvcb Google is your friend, I searched for "car battery cycles" and lots of links come up. Some batteries are designed for lifetime cycles measured in 1000, others are different. See https://www.batteriesplus.com/blog/power/battery-discharge-cycle and https://www.carbibles.com/car-battery-life/

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will be searching forward

Answer (score 4):

Car batteries are made in huge volume and are a regular maintenance item so they're available everywhere (and are recycled properly in most cases). Computer UPS batteries, less so. Car batteries (at least here) tack on a charge that is only refunded when a similar battery is returned for recycling. The UPS batteries tend to be gel cell types, which is slightly different from car batteries. Also AGM (absorbed glass mat) car batteries cost much more, and deep cycle batteries (eg. for pallet lifters, marine etc.) use more materials and are also much more expensive.

That said, the last ordinary car batteries I purchased were around the equivalent of $110 USD plus tax each, whereas the last couple pairs of 9ah UPS batteries cost $44 USD per pair ($22 USD each battery) plus tax with free shipping inside the US.

Of course if I went to the UPS maker for an "official" Chinese battery rather than the less official but still well-rated eBay units, the cost would have made replacement uneconomical (yes I checked before going to the trouble of dealing with that supplier), and a lot of UPS units end up trashed for that reason. Corporations are more likely to just trash them than have them refurbished- it's a pretty small part of total computer costs.

Comment: You did not mention car battery capacity You bought

Comment: @Ngdgvcb Around 55 or 60 Ah.

Answer (score 4):

### Car batteries are not as capable as UPS batteries

The UPS application requires a modest to medium draw for a significant amount of time, e.g. 10-20 minutes. That is called *deep cycling* as you are drawing slow but using a significant amount of the battery's storage.

Car batteries are optimized for exactly one thing: starting an engine.  Everything in their design is optimized to produce a kiloamp surge of current for a few seconds, and then be rapidly recharged.  This *compromises away* their ability to perform well as a **deep-cycle** battery; ask anyone who has a habit of leaving their lights on.  Deep discharge degrades all lead-acid batteries, but it degrades engine starting batteries *much worse*.

**Commodity.**  Engine starting is the primary use of lead-acid batteries, which makes sense because it's the one thing they excel at.  As such you have *huge* economies of scale.  And, they must be replaced 2-3 times in the service life of an automobile, so they are everywhere with hot competition.  More shops sell car batteries than sell baking soda lol.  Whereas if any retail shop in your city carries a UPS battery, they don't have much competition and they know it.

**Shipping.** Because of their ubiquity, they are sold in high volume at retail shops, and so they truck-ship by the pallet load as part of existing distribution chains. It's *not even* Swift delivering an LTL pallet; it's NAPA delivering an entire truck of mixed auto parts to the retailer. The comparative rarity of UPS batteries does not allow this type of hyper-efficient distribution, and that too is reflected in the price.